# Using react native with firestore get().data() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm just wondering what's wrong with the way I'm fetching data
using firebase with react-native

why does this work

```
const res = await firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).get();
const data = res.data().todos.todo.work
```

but this way I get undefined

```
const res = await firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).collection('todos').doc('todo').get();
const data = res.data().work
```

I also tried this but got undefined as well

```
const res = await firestore().collection('users').doc(`${uid}/todos/todo`).get();
const data = res.data().work
```

what exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your database, I can only guess that you only have a single document and no actual subcollections.  It looks like your single document has nested *fields* call "todo" inside it.  A nested field in a document can't be fetched individually using special syntax.  You can only read an entire document at once.

Nested fields in Firestore are **not** subcollections.  They are just fields within a single document.  The syntax in the second code sample that doesn't work is attempting to read a document in a subcollection, which simply doesn't exist.

I would suggest reviewing the documentation to better understand how fields and subcollections work, and the code you would use to access either one.

Comment: thx, this is what I'm missing i thought a map type is a collection

Comment: A map is just a type of field that contains other nested fields.  If you found this answer helpful, please upvote it and mark it as correct using the buttons to the left.